# Any way to have double->float conversion regarded as "widening"?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, floating-point, type-conversion

Is there any way to tell vb.net (2010) to allow expressions of type Double to be passed to parameters expecting Float, without having to use an explicit CSng() calls, other than by turning off all complaints related to narrowing conversions?  Given that a Double->Single conversion will never throw an exception, and given that precision loss does not seem to be a criterion for regarding a conversion as "Narrowing" (Long->Double is considered "Widening" despite the fact that it involves an inexact conversion from an "exact-value" type to an "approximate-value" type; a Double->Single conversion merely goes from an "approximate-value" type to a "somewhat-more-approximate-value" type, so it is in some sense less lossy).

I know turning off Option Strict would eliminate squawks about Double->Single conversion, but that is incredibly massively overkill.  Is there any way to stifle all complaints about Double->Single, without stifling other possibly-useful squawks?

**Edit**

If Microsoft isn't going to allow code to be written in the most logical fashion, would it be preferable to litter the code with CSng() every time I call graphics methods, or define NewRectF and NewPointF methods which accept doubles and then use the RectF/PointF overloads for the graphics methods, or would something else be better still?

Comment: A conversion may not throw an exception, but doubles can represent much larger values than floats.  If the double is outside the range for floats, you could end up with "infinity".

Comment: @cHao: Sure, an overly large number could turn into "infinity", but a lot of operations with floats or doubles could turn into "infinity".  When passing values to graphics routines, the danger of having something convert to Infinity is minuscule compared to the danger of having the graphics routines' intermediate calculations overflow, which can happen with values much smaller than 1E+38.

Answer (score 1):

I believe not, and (more importantly) if you can, I advise to not do it. In the best case, your tests will find the faulty data that members of your team might create by such a sorry compiler flag. In the worst case, your application's faulty data will go completely unnoticed.

Argument:

I'm afraid your logic is fallacious. While it's true that long accurately represents integers (in the range of longs), while double is an approximation of real numbers, it's not true that the *conversion* from long to double is inexact. (If unsure about this, check it out yourself with the program below.) No data will be lost when casting from long to double, so it's by definition non-narrowing. Such casts are thus not going to introduce errors on their own (although various errors may be introduced by treating double as real numbers).

This is certainly not true when casting from doubles to floats. If that wouldn't introduce data loss, we would always use floats, as they use less memory). It may be OK in some cases to cast a double to float, but the programmer should "vouch" for it. This he does by explicitly casting (using CSng).

```
Function DataLostWhenCasting(ByVal l As Long)
    Dim d As Double
    Dim e As Double

    d = l ' The cast (implicit)
    ' Check for lost data:
    e = d - l
    If e > 0 Then
        Return True
    End If

    Return False
End Function

Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine(DataLostWhenCasting(Long.MinValue))
    Console.WriteLine(DataLostWhenCasting(Long.MaxValue))
End Sub
```

Comment: The conversion from `long` to `double` *is* inexact if the `long` uses more than 53 bits.  However, you don't lose *range* in the conversion like you would with `long` to `short` or `double` to `float`.

Comment: If P=(1<<60)+1 and Q=(1<<60), P-Q should equal one.  Convert to doubles and compute the difference, and it would equal zero.  As for range loss, there are many functions which take an argument of type 'float' which will malfunction with values way below 1E38.  The risk of data loss is way below the risk of overflows from other causes.

Comment: MS documentation: "Conversions from Integer, UInteger, Long, ULong, or Decimal to Single or Double might result in loss of precision, but never in loss of magnitude. In this sense they do not incur information loss." Isn't it convenient, at least in practical terms, to view it as an exact conversion if information is not lost.

Comment: In many applications, a change in the bottom digit of an integer may be of far more relevance than the conversion of 1E+39 to +INF.  Further, it feels very odd that one cannot add 0.5 to a Single variable; one has to add "0.5!" (with the exclamation mark), even though there would be no loss of precision with the addition.

Comment: Most widening type conversions convert something to a form which is less specific, but no less correct.  Compute the square of double-precision floating point numbers 0.1, cast the result to Float, and print it.  Now start with single-precision 0.1, do the multiply, cast the result to Double, and print that.  The more I think about it, the more I think that float to double maybe should have been a narrowing conversion; in any case, there's no reason not to regard double to float as widening.

Answer (score 0):

no, it's not possible

you have to convert it

or convert your code to use only double or only float(single)

Comment: I'd use Double for everything if I could, but most of the drawing routines use floats.  In many situations single precision is more than adequate for PointF, and it's common to have large arrays of them, so spending 8 bytes each would be overkill.  Am I the only one who finds all the silly typecasts to float annoying?